# Scale in different units

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale, react-d3

How to use D3 to convert and display the right information from different units

E.g.

[image]

All data is in `mm`..

```
[ 
    { label: 'sample1', x: 300 }, 
    { label: 'sample2', x: 1200 }, 
    { label: 'sample3', x: 4150 } 
]
```

So, the question is, how can I create a scale that understand the `sample3` should be point in same place after the 4 and before 5.

**Consider**

1. 10000, its just a sample, can be 102301 or any value
2. I want to use D3 scale if possible to do this conversion

### Attempt

```
let scaleX = d3.scale.linear().domain([-10, 10]).range([0, 500]) // Missing the mm information...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conceptual problem here:

- Mapping an input (domain) to an output (range): that's the task of the **scale**.
- Formatting the number and the unit (if any) in the axis: that's the task of the **axis generator**

Thus, in your scale, you'll have to set the domain to accept the raw, actual data (that is, the data the way it is) you have:

```
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-10000, 10000])//the extent of your actual data
    .range([min, max]);
```

Then, in the axis generator, you change the value in the display. Here, I'm simply dividing it by 1000 and adding "mm":

```
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
    .tickFormat(d => d / 1000 + "mm");
```

Note that I'm using D3 v4 in these snippets.

Here is a demo using these values: -7500, 500 and 4250. You can see that the circles are in the adequate position, but the axis shows the values in mm.

```js
var data = [-7500, 500, 4250];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 200);

var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-10000, 10000])
  .range([20, 480]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(d => d / 1000 + "mm");

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("fill", "teal")
  .attr("cy", 40)
  .attr("cx", d => scale(d));

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,60)")
  .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: yep.. this was my answer.  There are only one difference, I create a `scaleFormat` because I need to fix my range between -10 and 10.

Comment: I believe your answer is different from this... For instance, you never use `scaleFormat` in your code, don't you agree?

Comment: I never use because the `ticksFormat` should be use by `axis` object. I don`t put the complete code here. That`s the reason that I mark your answer. Are more completed that mine

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that..

```
const SIZE_MM = 10000
const SIZE_PX = 500
const scaleFormat = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, SIZE_MM]).range([-10, 10])
const ticksFormat = d => Math.round(scaleFormat(d))
const ticks = SIZE_MM / SIZE_PX 

const lineScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, SIZE_MM ]).range([0, SIZE_PX])
lineScale(9500)
// 475
```